# In Angular 4 and above versions is it good way to implement a dynamic module loading. If so can you explain me with an example.

Tags: javascript, angular

Can we achieve dynamic module loading in angular 4. If so is this a best practice ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, and in the Angular world it's commonly called ***lazy loading an Angular module***. Basically, you use *loadChildren* for the route that is being loaded lazily, with a file path pointing to the lazy module. Then that module will have it's own components, etc. that will be loaded when the module is loaded.

See these links for more info:

- https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/lazy-loading-in-angular-v2

And here's an example of how the code might look:

routes.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { EagerComponent } from './eager.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'eager', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'eager', component: EagerComponent },
  { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

LazyModule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { LazyComponent }   from './lazy.component';
import { routing } from './lazy.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [routing],
  declarations: [LazyComponent]
})
export class LazyModule {}
```

LazyRouting

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LazyComponent } from './lazy.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LazyComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apart from Lazy loading, the requirement what i have is on the fly I will come to know what module has to be loaded

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apart from Lazy loading, the requirement what i have is  1: On the fly (JSON response will have the module names list) I will come to know what modules has to be loaded in the page. So how to inject them upon the page at run time.